# Can you explain me the output of following C code?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 258;
    char *b = &a;
    b++;
    *b =2;
    printf("%d",a);
return 0;
}
```

*Value of a is coming out to be 514 but I'm not sure how?!*

Comment: 258 = 1*256 + 2. 514 = 2*256 + 2. You changed the 1 to 2.

Answer (score 5):

`258` will look something like `00000000 00000000 00000001 00000010` ( on little-endian).

You then make `b` point to the "first `char`" which is `00000010`.

Now you increment `b`, because it's of type `char` it now moves to next addressable `char` which is `00000001` (the "second" element) and then you change it to `2` which is `00000010`.

So now we have `00000000 00000000 00000010 00000010` which is `514` when read as an `int`.

This result is not guaranteed though as on big-endian the result will differ as a whole.

Comment: This answer assumes the integers are stored in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) notation (which probably **is** the actual byte-order on the poster's computer, given the results they get).

Answer (score 2):

Given a 32 bit 2's complement system, the variable `a` could be stored in the following ways (hex):

```
02 01 00 00 // little endian, or
00 00 01 02 // big endian
```

You point at the first byte of this integer, then increase the pointer by 1. On a little endian system you'll now point at the value `01` and on a big endian system you'll now point at the value `00`.

It seems you have a little endian system, since you change the value `01` to `02` and cause the memory to look like `02 02 00 00`. Translating this to a decimal number will give you 514.

Answer (score 2):

Think of `a` as an array of bytes (`char`) with `sizeof(int)` elements.

With

```
char *b = &a;
```

you make `b` point to the first element in this array.

Then you do `b++` which makes `b` point to the second element. You then assign a value to this second element, which will modify the value of `a`.

Also note that the results depends *very* much on the byte-order of your system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on a little endian system:

```
int a = 258
```

A 4 byte number which represents in Hex 0x00000102

```
char *b = &a;
```

Make a pointer to a one byte size datatype, so it only points to the last 0x02

```
b++;
```

Move the pointer up 1 byte, now it points to the 0x01

```
*b = 2;
```

Change the second byte of your int from 0x01 to 0x02
Now you have

```
a = 0x00000202 = 514
```

Comment: This answer assumes the integers are stored in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) notation (which probably **is** the actual byte-order on the poster's computer, given the results they get).

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 258;
```

Assuming int is 4 bytes long in your machine, it will be stored as

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 00000010
```

When you do `char *b = &a;`, b will be pointing to the first byte from the right which is 00000010.

When you do `b++;` assuming char is 1 byte in your machine, b value is incremented by 1 and now it is pointing to 2nd byte from right which is 00000001.

Now you do `*b =2;`. So 2nd byte will become `00000010`.

So if you see, `a`, it will be like this.

```
00000000 00000000 00000010 00000010
```

Which is 512.

Answer (score -1):

integer type 'b' variable's second byte will be incremented as the a variable is of char type. And your answer will change to 514